# Modifying SDK API in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to modify FingerprintGestureController API in AOSP (master branch) to return boolean rather than void but I am keep getting error in building the project even after recompiling the SDK.

Error is:

```
FAILED: out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-last-timestamp
/bin/bash -c "(( out/host/linux-x86/bin/apicheck -JXmx1024m -J\"classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/../lib/tools.jar:out/host/linux-x86/framework/doclava.jar:out/host/linux-x86/framework/jsilver.jar\"  -hide 2 -hide 3 -hide 4 -hide 5 -hide 6 -hide 24 -hide 25 -hide 26 -hide 27 -error 7 -error 8 -error 9 -error 10 -error 11 -error 12 -error 13 -error 14 -error 15 -error 16 -error 17 -error 18   prebuilts/sdk/api/26.txt  out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt  frameworks/base/api/removed.txt  out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/removed.txt || (  cat build/core/apicheck_msg_last.txt ; exit 38 ) ) ) && (mkdir -p out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/ ) && (touch out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-last-timestamp )"
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:2874: error 16: Method android.accessibilityservice.FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback.onGestureDetected(int) has changed return type from Primitive?: true TypeVariable?: false Wildcard?: false Dimension:  QualifedTypeName: void to Primitive?: true TypeVariable?: false Wildcard?: false Dimension:  QualifedTypeName: boolean

******************************
You have tried to change the API from what has been previously released in
an SDK.  Please fix the errors listed above.
******************************
```

Steps I followed to compile are:

```
lunch sdk-eng
make update-api   //Success
make sdk         //Success
lunch 1
make -j10      //Errors out here
```

Can someone please guide how I can change the android's released SDK API in source code and compile android.

Comment: `onGestureDetected` is an interface callback. What purpose do you gain from making it a boolean return type, and attempting to block on the method call?

Comment: I want to find out if the application who received the fingerprint gesture callback has consumed the event or not, similar to View's onTouch events.

Comment: And why would it not? If the device has no fingerprint sensor?

Comment: Fingerprint callbacks are delivered through accessibility service. Which means that even if app is not in foreground it can receive the callback. Let's say that an app want to consume fingerprint gesture only if it's in foreground 
 because only in that scenario it's sensible for it otherwise just pass it on. For example: If camera is in foreground then only swipe would move from camera to video mode and say that it has consumed it, otherwise it can return that it is not consuming it and system should handle swipe to toggle notification bar.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the following files have been updated with your method signature changes:

```
/frameworks/base/api/current.txt
/frameworks/base/api/system-current.txt
/frameworks/base/api/test-current.txt
```

Comment: Those files are already updated and showing the updated api. Also I mentioned that make update-api and make sdk was successful.

Answer (score 0):

**Just one more hint**: have you actually modified `api/26.txt` file accordingly to reflect your API changes before you proceeded with `make update-api`?